# Configuring i2c on a Raspberry Pi2

Tags: i2c, temperature

I am trying to connect a Temp and Humi probe Adafruit AM2315 and it seams that the only thing I need to do is to get i2c running on my Pi2. I can't seams to find the proper instructions or command line to get it config and running ? Can someone help ?

Answer (score 0):

did you connect it directly to the RPi2 I2C pins, or did you use the 10KOhm resistors too..?

It seems it needs two rapid connections to wake up first, before starting to send commands, see here:

http://raspberrypihobbyist.blogspot.it/2015/02/using-am2315-temperaturehumidity-sensor.html

David